# Chromium: QR-Code for Whatsapp Web doesn't load

Tags: chromium, web-browsers, pi-b+, web

I want to make a python program controlling my browser on my Raspberry Pi Model B+ using Raspberry Pi OS, but am running into a very basic issue. When opening web.whatsapp.com on the installed Chromium browser, the QR code used to link one's phone with the web app doesn't load.
[image: the page that should have a qr code]
I have not run into issues on other websites, which is why I belive it has something to do with Whatsapp Web. Research led me to other problems people have when using Whatsapp Web on their Raspberry, but nobody mentioned the QR code not even loading. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: most people cannot read the message in the picture

Comment: you are having a problem with a chromium browser on a linux computer ... research in the Linux realm, not in Raspberry Pi realm

Comment: @jsotola Oh yeah, you're right, sorry. What forum would be fit for my question? Just AskUbuntu? I can't really find any active chromium forums.